# Android force close after sending data to server via php

Tags: php, android, sql, sql-server

I have a program to read data from SQL Server using php file. When I running my program and click the button search my program always close. In my logcat no one error message

My code android like this

```
Toolbar toolbar;
// Progress Dialog
private ProgressDialog pDialog;

JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
EditText inputign;
TextView registerErrorMsg;
Button searchign;
// url to create news
private static String url_create_idgm = "http://192.168.1.111/add/csp_ign.php";

// JSON Node names
private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_cps_ign);

    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    TypedValue typedValueColorPrimaryDark = new TypedValue();
    CSPviaIGN.this.getTheme().resolveAttribute(R.attr.colorPrimary, typedValueColorPrimaryDark, true);
    final int colorPrimaryDark = typedValueColorPrimaryDark.data;
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
        getWindow().setStatusBarColor(colorPrimaryDark);
    }

    // Edit Text
    inputign = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputign);
    registerErrorMsg = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.error);
    // Create button
    searchign = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnign);

    // button click event
    searchign.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // creating new product in background thread
            new NetCheck().execute();
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Background Async Task to Create new product
 * */
class NetCheck extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    /**
     * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(CSPviaIGN.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Creating ID Game Master..");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    /**
     * Creating product
     * */
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        String name = inputign.getText().toString();

        // Building Parameters
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("ign", name));

        // getting JSON Object
        // Note that create product url accepts POST method
        JSONObject obj = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_create_idgm,
                "POST", params);

        // check log cat fro response
        Log.d("Create Response", obj.toString());

        // check for success tag
        try {
            int success = obj.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

            if (success == 1) {
                // successfully created product
                //Toast.makeText(CreateIDGM.this, "Success Create ID Game Master ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                //JSONObject obj = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_create_idgm, "GET", params);
                JSONArray account = obj.getJSONArray("detail");
                JSONObject firstOnlineObject = account.getJSONObject(0);
                String accountign = firstOnlineObject.getString("Account");

                JSONArray ign = obj.getJSONArray("detail");
                JSONObject secondOnlineObject = ign.getJSONObject(0);
                String Name = secondOnlineObject.getString("Name");

                JSONArray race = obj.getJSONArray("detail");
                JSONObject thirdOnlineObject = race.getJSONObject(0);
                String bangsa = thirdOnlineObject.getString("Race");

                JSONArray classign = obj.getJSONArray("detail");
                JSONObject forthOnlineObject = classign.getJSONObject(0);
                String job = forthOnlineObject.getString("Class");

                JSONArray map = obj.getJSONArray("detail");
                JSONObject fifthOnlineObject = map.getJSONObject(0);
                String location = fifthOnlineObject.getString("Map");

                JSONArray level = obj.getJSONArray("detail");
                JSONObject sixthOnlineObject = level.getJSONObject(0);
                String Lv = sixthOnlineObject.getString("Level");

                JSONArray dalant = obj.getJSONArray("detail");
                JSONObject seventhOnlineObject = dalant.getJSONObject(0);
                String money = seventhOnlineObject.getString("Dalant");

                JSONArray gold = obj.getJSONArray("detail");
                JSONObject eighthOnlineObject = gold.getJSONObject(0);
                String emas = eighthOnlineObject.getString("Gold");

                JSONArray pvp = obj.getJSONArray("detail");
                JSONObject ninthOnlineObject = pvp.getJSONObject(0);
                String pvppoint = ninthOnlineObject.getString("PVP Point");

                JSONArray cpt = obj.getJSONArray("detail");
                JSONObject tenOnlineObject = cpt.getJSONObject(0);
                String cptpoint = tenOnlineObject.getString("CPT Point");

                JSONArray cc = obj.getJSONArray("detail");
                JSONObject ccOnlineObject = cc.getJSONObject(0);
                String cashcoin = ccOnlineObject.getString("Cash Coin");

                JSONArray ps = obj.getJSONArray("detail");
                JSONObject psOnlineObject = ps.getJSONObject(0);
                String premi = psOnlineObject.getString("Premium Service");

                // TextView data
                TextView id = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.accountplayer);
                id.setText(accountign); // id
                TextView ignname = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.ignPlayer);
                ignname.setText(Name); // ign
                TextView raceign = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.serialplayer);
                raceign.setText(bangsa); // race
                TextView jobign = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.raceplayer);
                jobign.setText(job); // job
                TextView mapign = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.classplayer);
                mapign.setText(location); // map
                TextView lvign = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.lvlplayer);
                lvign.setText(Lv); //level
                TextView dalantign = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.dalantplayer);
                dalantign.setText(money); // dalant
                TextView goldign = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.goldplayer);
                goldign.setText(emas); // gold
                TextView pvpign = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.pvpplayer);
                pvpign.setText(pvppoint); // pvp
                TextView cptign = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.cptplayer);
                cptign.setText(cptpoint); //cpt
                TextView cashign = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.cc);
                cashign.setText(cashcoin); // cash
                TextView premiign = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.premi);
                premiign.setText(premi); // premi

                // closing this screen
                finish();
            } else {
                // failed to create product
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog once done
        pDialog.dismiss();
        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), CSPviaIGN.class);
        //i.putExtra("key",inputign.getText().toString());
        startActivity(i);
    }
}
```

My code php like this

```
<?php
 //$_POST['ign'] = "CaptainJugger";
 // array for JSON response
 $response = array();
 // check for required fields
 if (isset($_POST['ign'])) {

$ign = $_POST['ign'];

/* All database connection variables */
define('DB_USER', ""); // db user
define('DB_PASSWORD', ""); // db password
define('DB_DATABASE', "RF_World"); // database name
define('DB_SERVER', "127.0.0.1"); // db server

class DB_CONNECT {
    // constructor
    function __construct() {
        // connecting to database
        $this->connect();
    }

    // destructor
    function __destruct() {
        // closing db connection
        $this->close();
    }

    /** Function to connect with database **/
    function connect() {

        // Connecting to mssql database
        $con = mssql_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD) or die(mssql_error());

        // Selecing database
        $db = mssql_select_db(DB_DATABASE) or die(mssql_error()) or die(mssql_error());

        // returing connection cursor
        return $con;
    }

    /** Function to close db connection **/
    function close() {
        // closing db connection
        mssql_close();
    }
}

// connecting to db
$db = new DB_CONNECT();

// mssql inserting a new row
$result = mssql_query("SELECT Account, Name, Race, Class, Map, Lv, Dalant, Gold, c.PvpPoint, PvpCash, Cash, d.Status FROM tbl_base a
INNER JOIN tbl_general b ON b.Serial = a.Serial 
INNER JOIN tbl_pvporderview c ON c.serial = a.Serial
INNER JOIN [BILLING].[dbo].tbl_UserStatus d ON d.id = a.Account
WHERE Name= '$ign';");
// status premium service
    if ($res['Status'] == 1){
        $status = 'Deactive';
    } else {
        $status = 'Active';
    }
    // status race
    if ($res['Race'] == 0){
        $race = 'Bellato';
    } elseif ($res['Race'] == 1){
        $race = 'Bellato';
    } elseif ($res['Race'] == 2){
        $race = 'Cora';
    } elseif ($res['Race'] == 3){
        $race = 'Cora';
    } else {
        $race = 'Accretia';
    }
// check if row inserted or not
if (mssql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // looping through all results
    // products node
    $response["detail"] = array();

    while ($row = mssql_fetch_array($result)) {

        // temp user array
        $product = array();
        $product["Account"] = $row["Account"];
        $product["Name"] = $row["Name"];
        $product["Race"] = $row["Race"];
        $product["Class"] = $row["Class"];
        $product["Map"] = $row["Map"];
        $product["Level"] = $row["Lv"];
        $product["Dalant"] = $row["Dalant"];
        $product["Gold"] = $row["Gold"];
        $product["PVP Point"] = $row["PvpCash"];
        $product["CPT Point"] = $row["PvpPoint"];
        $product["Cash Coin"] = $row["Cash"];
        $product["Premium Service"] = $row["Status"];

        // push single product into final response array
        array_push($response["detail"], $product);
    }
    // success
    $response["success"] = 1;

    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
} else {
    // no products found
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "No News DZoneConnect Now";
} 

}
else {
// required field is missing
$response["success"] = 0;
$response["message"] = "Required field(s) is missing";

// echoing JSON response
echo json_encode($response);
}
?>
```

My code php when I run in browser like this http://prntscr.com/bfjl5a and http://prntscr.com/bfjlf3

Anyone can help me to solve my problem?

Comment: There is a call "finish()" with comment "closing this screen". Isn't that closing the activity?

Comment: I already delete the finish() but still force close

Comment: Ok. Another thing is that you are calling UI methods (TextView.setText) from background thread (in doInBackground). I think you should store the results and only call UI methods from UI thread (in onPostExecute or post to UI thread). However, if this is the issue, you should see some trace in logcat when app is force closed.

Comment: @TeemuLätti no message in logcat sir

Comment: @TeemuLätti when i put in onPostExecute get error like this http://prntscr.com/bfq6c7

Comment: @TeemuLätti when i put in onPostExecute get error like this http://prntscr.com/bfq6c7

Comment: Leave the code that makes http request and takes strings from JSON objects in original place in doInBackground, but move only the code that calls setText methods (everything after comment "TextView data"). To pass the string values between these methods, you need also move them as members instead of local variables.